# Connectedness properties of groups of homeomorphisms

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Denote by $H(X)$ the group of homeomorphisms of a topological space $X$. Assume further that $X$ is either compact or locally compact and locally connected. In both cases $H(X)$ becomes a topological group with respect to the compact open topology $\tau_C$.

What can be said about the connectedness of $(H(X),\tau_C)$?

I would really like to get some references regarding this question and/or  the more general one: for a connected space $X$, what topologies (eg. compact-open,pointwise, uniform)  make $C(X)$ connected?

These questions arose from  this specific one:

How can I prove that the group $H_+(S^1)$ (orientation preserving homeomorphisms of the circle) is connected?

Comment: What is $C(X)$?

Comment: The specific question about connectedness of $H_+(S^1)$ is easy to treat explicitly: you can just write down a path between any homeo and the identity.

Comment: @Ludolila. Have you read about the mapping class group? Essentially the mapping class group of a space is the group of autohomeomorphisms modulo the subgroup of autohomeomorphisms isotopic to the identity. In particular, the mapping class group is the collection of all path components in $Aut(X)$.

Comment: @JohnPardon $C(X)$-the space of all continuous functions on $X$.

Comment: @Ludolila: well then $C(X)$ is a vector space and thus contractible.

Comment: @JosephVanName No, I haven't even heard about it. Just finished reading about it in Wikipedia, and it's very interesting! Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @JohnPardon: Just to make sure: if $C(X)$ is a topological vector space, then it will be path connected. So the answer to the question "which topologies make $C(X)$ connected" is "the topologies that make $C(X)$ a topological vector space"?

Comment: According to Comfort (chap. 24 in handbook of set-theoretic topology, pag. 1242) citing de Groot, the groups of homeomorphism of compact connected spaces are arbitrary groups, and so the discrete topology might be the only group topology. @Ludolila might want stronger conditions on $X$ to have a topological group $H(X)$

Comment: @user46855 I took $X$ to be locally compact and *locally* connected (and Hausdorff). In this case the compact open topology turns $H(X)$ into a topological group. See for example "Topologies for homeomorphisms groups" by Arens. I will check Comfort, though, sounds interesting.

Comment: @Ludolila sorry, my poor English made me understand "(compact) or (locally compact and locally connected)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the last part of your question:

Let $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ be two orientation preserving homeomorphism in $H_{+}(S^{1})$. Lift $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ to homeomorphisms $F_{0}$ and $F_{1}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, as in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_number.

Then consider the quotient of the homotopy  $F_{t}=tF_{0}+(1-t)F_{1}$ as a path of homeomorphism on $S^{1}$.

More  precisely let $P:\mathbb{R}\to S^{1}$ be the standard quotient map. Then  $G_{t}=P \circ F_{t}$ is  a path of maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to $S^{1}$, which satisfies $G_{t}(x+1)=G_{t}$. In the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/P=S^{1}$ we obtain a path of orientation preserving homeomorphisms which connects $f_{0}$ to $f_{1}$.

Comment: Thank you! The truth is, I am not very familiar with these methods, though I do encounter the notion of rotation number every once in a while. I thought that maybe there is a more set-theoretic topological approach?

Comment: @Ludolila In fact we do not need to "rotation number". We need only to lift a homeomorphism  $f$ of $S^{1}$ to a homeomorphism $F$ of $R$. This statment is written in the first line after the definition of the above link